# How to enable a panel after video finish playing

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, video, panel

How to enable a panel after video finish playing in unity

```
public class LoadPanelAfterVideoEnds : MonoBehaviour
{
    public VideoPlayer VideoPlayer; // Drag & Drop the GameObject holding the VideoPlayer component
    public GameObject Panel;

    void Start()
    {
        VideoPlayer.loopPointReached += LoadPanel;
    }

    public void LoadPanel(VideoPlayer vp)
    {
        Panel.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. The code looks fine, what's the problem that you're having?

Comment: Its not setting the panel active, I want it to turn the panel on after the video finish playing

Comment: I don't use Unity (you tagged `video`) but since the LoadPanel function requires a **function parameter** of type VideoPlayer so try as : `VideoPlayer.loopPointReached += LoadPanel(VideoPlayer);` PS: Don't use variable names that are exactly like API keywords. Look at `public VideoPlayer VideoPlayer;` now If I say `VideoPlayer` am I talking about the API (left-side) or the variable (right-side)? They have the same name, it will confuse the machine later as your code gets bigger / complicated.

Comment: Seems like there's an issue with the video player. If there is no looping involved in the video clip then the callback doesn't trigger. Try some solutions from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-know-video-player-is-finished-playing-video.483935/).

Comment: @Seve you problem has to be somewhere else as your code works perfectly fine for me: https://imgur.com/mN2d7i7

Comment: @VC.One nope! the `VideoPlayer` parameter is already returned by the `loopPointReached` event handler. Also .. *the machine* will never be confused because one of them is a class in `UnityEngine.Video.VideoPlayer` the other one is a property `LoadPanelAfterVideoEnds.VideoPlayer` ... it is only confusing to read it for us here ;)

Comment: @derHugo So how do I fix this

Comment: @Seve I don't know ... I took your script and didn't change anything, plugged it into a video player which used a URL. And dragged in the penguin panel ... -> no issues https://imgur.com/mN2d7i7 . Is it possible that in your case the parent object of the panel is also inactive? Btw since `Panel` already is a `GameObject` you can skip the additional `gameObject`

Comment: @derHugo Thanks so much I tried it, now it works, I didn't keep the parent object active